# Xamarin Forms - Change back button image

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I can successfully hide the back button but can't change image of button.

To hide back button:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(page, bool);
```

There is Icon attribute but we need to change back button image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to override the `NavigationBar` on each particular OS you have.

For **Android** you will need to look at the `ToolBar` and on **iOS** is the `NavigationBar`.

Refer :

- https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/
- https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/navigation_controller/change_the_back_button/

Comment: It would be better to include information on how to do this in the answer itself; your first link is dead, for instance.